# Service doesnot stop after activity destroy

Tags: android, service

I have written a service with timer to do something periodically  but when I stop service service from mainActivity if my service is in middle of their task it's continue to finish and after that stop it and the same issue when i want to close application that call OnDestroy on Main Activity service work and after finish their task don't start again.
My Question is how can Force stop service when i want to exit from my app?
this is my service code

```
public class MyTimerService extends Service{

private static int counter = 0;

private Timer timer = new Timer();
private int INTERVAL;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    INTERVAL = intent.getIntExtra("time", 500);
    repaet();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

private void repaet() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Saeed", String.valueOf(++counter));
        }
    }, 0, INTERVAL);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Stop Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(timer!=null){
        timer.cancel();
    }       
    stopSelf();
    super.onDestroy();
}

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to manually stop your service inside onDestroy() by using this [stopService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29)?

Comment: No, I stop service onBackPressed() but i override onDestory() and it's working but my service doesn't stop

Comment: this is my code
@Selz
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(backPressTime < (System.currentTimeMillis()-3000)){
   Toast.makeText(this, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   backPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }else{
   saveSendConfiguration();
   if(serviceCall != null){
    context.stopService(serviceCall);    
   }
   super.onBackPressed();
  }
 }

Comment: I was asking because of something documentation says about services. that is: "When a service is started, it has a lifecycle that's independent of the component that started it and the service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed. As such, the service should stop itself when its job is done by calling stopSelf(), or another component can stop it by calling stopService()"

Comment: And I thought that could be the problem, but logic tells me that your code should work. You could try to make that call inside onDestroy(), just to make sure that onBackPressed() is not the problem. I'm sorry. I know this is not very helpful, but I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to check as you said.